# Even though my file has the string i look for, I still receive an error email through python

Tags: python, pandas

Even though my Rout file has the end_str in the exact format, I am still receiving the email alert. It should not send me an email at all because technically there is no error. Why does this happen?

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

df = pd.read_fwf(r'Service-Now-Data.Rout', header=None)
end_str = '#--- END ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
cols_to_check = ["0"]


def email_alert(subject,body,to):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(body)
    msg['subject'] = subject
    msg['to'] = to
        
    user = "DataScienceScriptAlerts@cfi.com"
    msg['from'] = user

        
    server = smtplib.SMTP("pmixx36.corp.hhhegroup.com", 2525)
    server.starttls()
    #server.login(user,password)
    server.send_message(msg)
        
    server.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for col in cols_to_check:
        if not df[0].str.contains(end_str).any():
            body = "There Service-Now-Data.R script in xxx had errors on the last execution" + col + "."
            print(body)
            email_alert("Service-Now-Data failure alert",body,"jtl.t@cfi.com")
```

the contents of df clearly have end_str

```
df[0]
Out[3]: 
0      R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) -- "Lost Library ...
1      Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statis...
2              Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
3      R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY N...
397                                                    >
398    > #--- END -----------------------------------...
399                                                    >
400                                        > proc.time()
401                                 user  system elapsed
402                                76.10    4.92  374.51
Name: 0, Length: 403, dtype: object
```

As you can see end_str exists in df and it still says false below

```
print(df[0].str.contains(end_str))
0      False
397    False
398    False
399    False
400    False
401    False
402    False
Name: 0, Length: 403, dtype: bool
```

Comment: could it be that you have missed a newline character or sth like that? also based on what I just read, the `end_str` doesn't have to equal the other string, there just has to be the same patter, meaning that you could try shortening your `end_str`

Comment: @matiiss no i verified, it is exactly the same number of characters taken n pasted from the rout file

Comment: also based on what I just read, the end_str doesn't have to equal the other string, there just has to be the same patter, meaning that you could try shortening your end_str, also try printing out `repr(string)` where `string` is the value you are comparing to, did you actually try to print what `df[0].str` is or `df[0]`?

Comment: You're not using the variable `col` in your check, but that shouldn't make a difference since you put "0" literally inside the loop. Might still be worth fixing.

Also, I'd shorten your example by removing the whole email function and replacing it with a `print('foo')` or whatever, and instead show the contents of df

Comment: What's the point of the loop if you never use `col`?

Comment: I suggest you simply do `print(df[0].str.contains(end_str))`

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with email or smtplib. It's entirely with your `if` statement that decides whether to send the alert.

Comment: @Barmar when i do print(df[0].str.contains(end_str)) it still says False for the line where the end_str exists

Comment: Then obviously it doesn't really contain `end_str`. Maybe the number of `-` is incorrect.

Comment: @Matiiss i have edited my question with df output

Comment: how about you simplify and do this: `end_str = 'END'`

Comment: i did end_str = 'END' and it did not send me an email. but isnt that incorrect? since it should detect the whole string?

Comment: you write "As you can see end_str exists in df and it still says false below" - to be fair, we can't *really* see that because the number of dashes gets cut off. I would propose testing for fewer dashes maybe?

Comment: @NewInPython No, `contains(end_str)` is true if `end_str` is anywhere in the string, it doesn't have to the whole string. You use `.str == end_str` to match the whole thing.

Comment: @Barmar but there are other words like append in the file that it is detecting too by that logic

Comment: How can `== end_str` match any other words? The dataframe cell has to match the string exactly.

Comment: I suggest you use a regular expression match instead of typing all the dashes. `#-{3} END -{99}`

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your error

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
end_str = '#--- END ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
df = pd.DataFrame([end_str])
print(df[0].str.contains(end_str))
```

```
0    True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

This implies that your end_str does not match with what is contained in the file

I would suggest double checking your end string in the rout file to make sure there aren't any breaks. Or shorten the string to just 'END'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
end_str = 'END'
df = pd.DataFrame(['#--- END ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'])
print(df[0].str.contains(end_str))
```

```
0    True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Answers should be used for solutions to the problem.

Comment: @Barmar Would the second part not be considered a solution?

Comment: I suppose, although it could have false positives of there are other rows containing `END` that shouldn't be matched.

Comment: @Barmar the first part shows that if the original string is contained it will match. Therefore something in that row breaks the ```end_str``` pattern. The simplest way to fix that would be to shorten the ```end_str``` if that does create false matches then perhaps ```end_str = '#--- END'```. The solution is shorten the match or fix the file.

Comment: We can't really provide a solution until we know what the actual problem is. He insists that the string he showed is in the dataframe, but obviously it's not. Yes, he needs to use a correct `end_str`, but what that is is hard to say without knowing more.

Comment: I feel like we are going a bit deep into the semantics. My goal was to show that ```str.contains``` is behaving how expected, and barring edge cases shortening ```end_str``` would fix it. I will keep that in mind in the future however.